# page redirection problem via Bean in Js1.1

Tags: jsf

I have a requested scoped managed bean, called `AuthenticationBean`. I am developing a smal application with a login module, user activation and deactivation.

When I click on the activate or deactivate link, then the action is processed in  `AuthenticationBean`. I want thereafter redirect to some page depending on the activate or deactivate link.

I have tried the following in the bean constructor:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/user/activate.jsp");
```

But this code is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Please don't put that much spaces in front of sentences. They would otherwise get formatted as code. Make use of the message preview section which you see below the message editor. I've fixed the text for you.

Comment: As to the "is not working" part: what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

> have tried the following in the bean constructor:

Do not try to redirect in the bean constructor - do it in an action method.

Comment: Hi Iam using this link http://localhost:8080/JSF_WEB_WFE/facesindex.jsp?confirmuser=rachel&emailid=valid when i click this link  it will call the Bean construction based on the link click it takes redirection . I wwant to redirect to another page .jhow to achieve this one.please help me.